# R2 value to find correlation between two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, correlation

Is it possible to find a Rsqaured value of two different dataset in order to find correlation?

For example, I have two dataframes as below

DataFrame 1

```
    Date      humidity  Average windspeed   sunshine    avg cloud
0   2016-01-01  93.714     2.855              1.622      5.925
1   2016-01-02  89.423     5.762              0.237      6.879
2   2016-01-03  87.281     6.138              0.978      6.308
```

DataFrame 2

```
        Date   Wind ene  wind offshore  Photovoltaic
0   2016-01-01  93.714      2.855             1.622      
1   2016-01-02  89.423      5.762             0.237     
2   2016-01-03  87.281      6.138             0.978
```

How would I find a correlation between these two dataframes?

Comment: R2 of what? How? You should provide an explicit logic and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain your goal? In my understanding, it makes less sense to find correlation between these two data frames.I would suggest you to find correlation between humidty and wind speed or investigate how the offshore and onshore wind speed look like if the wind speed in your first data frame is from onshore.

Comment: Understood that we can find R2 value of two different columns passed as a List. Thank you for the answer. It helped me to search more and finally got the answer.